# Issue with scatter3

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter3d

Probably it's `scatter3` what I don't understand. I have a matrix of which all slices but the last are NaNed (`M(:,:,1:10) = NaN;`) and then it's permuted switching first and last dimension. So there are only values in `M(11,:,:)`. I expect all plotted values to be in the Y-Z plane at `x==11`, but the plot looks differently (see code and picture below). Any explanations?

```
M = rand(22,55,11);
M(:,:,1:10) = NaN;
M = permute(M,[3 2 1]);

shape = size(M)
[x, y, z] = meshgrid(1:shape(1), 1:shape(2), 1:shape(3));
scatter3(x(:), y(:), z(:), 4, M(:), 'fill');
view([60 60]);
xlabel('X ', 'FontSize', 16);
ylabel('Y ', 'FontSize', 16);
zlabel('Z ', 'FontSize', 16);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is that `meshgrid` switches *x* and *y*:

From `meshgrid` documentation:

> MESHGRID is like NDGRID except that the order of the first two input
>       and output arguments are switched (i.e., [X,Y,Z] = MESHGRID(x,y,z)
>       produces the same result as [Y,X,Z] = NDGRID(y,x,z)).

At first sight, this should result in a plot with values in the *X-Z* plane at *y*==11 (i.e. *x* and *y* interchanged with respect to what you initially expected). But note that your code treats *x* and *y* sizes incorrectly (because of `meshgrid`). This has the additional effect that the `x` and `y` coordinates get "shuffled" and you don't see a plane (even in *X-Z*), but rather a lattice.

So the solution is to use `ndgrid`, which doesn't do any switching. Just replace "`meshgrid`" by "`ndgrid`" in your code. The resulting figure is now as expected:

[image]